# Update a column using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes **Employee** and **Department**.

```
public class Employee {
  int empId;
  String empName;
  Boolean isEmpAvailable;
  String empAddress;
  Department department;

 }


public class Department {
   int deptId;
   String deptName;
  }
```

I have created hibernate files files for both classes Department.hbm.xml and Employee.hbm.xml

I like to update the column isEmpAvailable in the table Employee basing on a deptid in Department table.

Here I am facing problem with update query which I am not clear after reading in online documentation

```
       public void updateEmployee(Employee emp, Department deptid){
          String query= " update Employee set isEmpAvailable=? where deptid=?   
          Object[] values= {"true","133"};
          getHibernateTemplate.update(query,values);
        }
```

When i run the code the column doesn't get update. A error is thrown as 
       Entity not recognized:  update Employee set isEmpAvailable=? where deptid=?

I have read online docs which have methods of getHibernateTemplate() which have return type as integer. Here I like to update the database directy by calling dao.updateEmployee without any returntype. I am unable do it. Please suggest me

Comment: Put @Entity annotation over both the classes.

Comment: Add complete stacktrace of error to your question. Also show your hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: This might help you to understand update in hibernate http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html

Comment: Complete hibernate update example : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-query-language-example/

Answer (score 2):

Update in hibernate is done this way :

```
String hqlUpdate =
    "update Employee e " +
    "set e.isEmpAvailable = :isEmpAvailable " +
    "where e.deptid = :deptid";
int updatedEntities = session.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
    .setBoolean( "isEmpAvailable", isEmpAvailable )
    .setInt( "deptid", deptid )
    .executeUpdate();

OR

String jpqlUpdate =
    "update Employee e " +
    "set e.isEmpAvailable = :isEmpAvailable " +
    "where e.deptid = :deptid";
int updatedEntities = entityManager.createQuery( jpqlUpdate )
    .setBoolean( "isEmpAvailable", isEmpAvailable )
    .setInt( "deptid", deptid )
    .executeUpdate();

OR

String hqlVersionedUpdate =
    "update versioned Employee e " +
    "set e.isEmpAvailable = :isEmpAvailable " +
    "where e.deptid = :deptid";
int updatedEntities = s.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
    .setBoolean( "isEmpAvailable", isEmpAvailable )
    .setInt( "deptid", deptid )
    .executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can also use the `saveOrUpdate()` function. In [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html) there is an example and some documentation.